# How to Customize Prompt Choice (Microsoft Botbuilder SDK)

Tags: node.js, botframework

### Note

I am using Microsoft Botbuilder SDK in `node.js` using ES6 babel.

### The Problem

Based on this helpful StackOverflow post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597651/3304185, I am trying to modify the behavior of builder.Prompts.choice **in the same way,** to have more control over the retry prompt instead of defaulting to "I didn't understand." However, when I try to follow this implementation pattern and apply it to builder.Prompts.choice, **I just get choices of `undefined` sent by the bot**, like so:

[image: Screenshot of Undefined Choices]

### Code

```
// snippet showing how I call the choice function, where
// welcome_subtitle is a string, and menuOptions is an array of strings
builder.Prompts.choice(session, welcome_subtitle, menuOptions, {
    listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
});

builder.Prompts.choice = (session, prompt, choices, options) => {
    let args = options || {};
    args.prompt = prompt || args.prompt;
    args.choices = choices || args.choices;

    args.retryPrompt = args.retryPrompt || args.prompt;
    session.beginDialog('BotBuilder:prompt-choice', args);
}
```

### Desired Behavior

I would have expected the choices to appear if I simply initialized `args.choice` to `choices || args.choices`, but that does not seem to be all that is necessary.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: Show us how you're calling the `choice` function - it looks like `prompt`, `choices`, and `options` are all `undefined`.

Comment: sure thing. I have edited my original post with the change. I have console.logged each of the args properties, and they are all defined (including args.choices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case passing in an array of `strings` will not work as it looks like the prompt is expecting a list of [`IChoice`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/b0bc71c487cb71e29703724204cdca7074617e43/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptRecognizers.ts#L91).

```
builder.Prompts.choice = (session, prompt, choices, options) => {
    let args = options || {};
    args.prompt = prompt || args.prompt;
    args.choices = choices || args.choices;

    args.retryPrompt = args.retryPrompt || args.prompt;
    console.log(args);
    session.beginDialog('BotBuilder:prompt-choice', args);
}

bot.dialog('/', [
    (session, args) => {
        welcome_subtitle = 'Hello Stack Overflow!';
        menuOptions = [{value: '1st Choice'}, {value: '2nd Choice'}, '3rd Choice', '4th Choice'];
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, welcome_subtitle, menuOptions, {
            listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button
        });
    },
    (session, results) => {
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```

Here's a screenshot with the `console.log(args)` inside `builder.Prompts.choice` and the emulator displaying the first two choices properly, but not the last two:

[image]

Comment: this works great! thank you very much for your help. one question for learning purposes: how did you know that this prompt was expecting an IPrompt instead of the also documented string, Object, or string[]?

Comment: I just checked the Prompts file to look for the interface of the method: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/Prompts.ts#L57 which referenced IChoice, and then at the actual implementation on the Prompts class and saw that it has more code that involves conversion of data to the expected format (IChoice): https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/Prompts.ts#L97